# How to Easily change my desktop background with a batch file in windows 10?

Tags: command-line

I have searched for a lot of codes, all of which only caused my background image to become black instead of changing to the image I want. However, I thought of another code for this. Please tell me whether this code will work or not and what is the difference, in terms of the effect, between this code and the other code that involves the registry and rundll32. In this code, I am attempting to change my background to a picture in my desktop called "Eye.jpg". This code "often" works, but when I restart, my background returns as it is. And I really mean "often" because at other times it doesn't work at all.

```
@echo off
xcopy /s/y "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Eye.jpg" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes"
del C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper
rename "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\Eye.jpg" "TranscodedWallpaper"
xcopy /s/y "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Eye.jpg" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles"
del C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles\CachedImage_1366_768_POS4.jpg
rename "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles\Eye.jpg" "CachedImage_1366_768_POS4.jpg"
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
pause
```

This was one of the other codes that didn't work out with me.

```
@echo off
call :quiet>nul 2>&1
goto :EOF
:quiet

reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /f /t REG_SZ /d %windir%:\Desktop\wallpaper.bmp

reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v WallpaperStyle /f /t REG_SZ /d 10


:: %SystemRoot%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

Comment: Is this a work or company computer?

Answer (score 1):

The registry method doesn't work all the time especially if the picture isn't in bmp format so you can try my method. It simply open the picture you want using windows photo viewer and use a keyboard shortcut to set the picture as your desktop wallpaper.

```
Dim wShell
set wShell = createobject("Wscript.shell")
wShell.Run "cmd /c start " & Your photo path here,0,True

do
     wscript.sleep 100
loop until wShell.appactivate("Windows Photo Viewer") = true

wShell.Sendkeys  ("+{F10}")
WScript.Sleep 100
wShell.Sendkeys  "k"
wShell.Exec "taskkill /im dllhost.exe"
```

This is a vbs script but you can use the same method using cmd

Answer (score 0):

Both methods will work, but in both cases, you made an error and its not working for that reason. I'll explain the error and how to fix it.

> @echo off
>   xcopy /s/y "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Eye.jpg" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes"
>   del C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper
>   rename "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\Eye.jpg" "TranscodedWallpaper"
>   xcopy /s/y "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Eye.jpg" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles"
>   del C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles\CachedImage_1366_768_POS4.jpg
>   rename "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles\Eye.jpg" "CachedImage_1366_768_POS4.jpg"
>   taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
>   start explorer.exe
>   pause

The above will change the background at the location windows stores backgrounds when a new background is set. The thing is, Windows will always convert the background to a .bmp image before setting it. You basically try to replace an image in .jpeg layout one that needs .bmp layout and assume it works, but a jpg image just is not a bmp image, and therefor windows can't load the image and does a failback to a black solid color.

To fix it, open your Eye.jpg file with a paint program, save it with the BMP (Bitmap) layout and extension to Eye.bmp, then use the new file in your script and it will work.

> @echo off
>   call :quiet>nul 2>&1
>   goto :EOF
>   :quiet
>   reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /f /t REG_SZ /d %windir%:\Desktop\wallpaper.bmp
>   reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v WallpaperStyle /f /t REG_SZ /d 10
>   :: %SystemRoot%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters

The above will set an image and make windows do its magic to convert the image to bmp and store it at the correct place.

The thing is, it is looking for %windir%\Desktop\wallpaper.bmp and not %userprofile%\Desktop\eye.jpg and therefor it doesn't work.

Either place a bmp version at %windir%\Desktop with the name wallpaper.bmp or change that path. Do note, if you change the path, it is possible that if you move the file elsewhere, your background will turn black on next reboot.

Comment: Actually, the script works, but returns back after restart. I am talking about the one that I thought of and was asking about in the Question (the first one).

Comment: Of course, I know that the second one requires a bmp image, but I wonder why the first one works before the restart only.

Comment: That is some very crucial information. You need to add such information to your question in order to get good answers. I don't know why it only works once though.